# Visual Studio 2017 wrong red highlight on export async functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

When writing modules in JS, VS highlight "export async function foo() { code }" as wrong syntax, but it's correct, webpack transpiles it correctly and everything works. I just want it to not be showed as error. It understands async, but using it with export confuses it greatly. I even tried disabling ESLint implemented in VS to no avail. How can I tell it that it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 15.8 fixed that.